# How to make resend email link function in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, authentication

I have this function that registers users pretty much the default from laravel auth, and i added this send email function. But now im wondering how can i make a function that will send again email if they click "resend link" for example if they didnt recieve the first time.

**Register function with the send email**:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
            'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
        ]);
        $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);
        $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        return $user;
    }
```

**And this is the sendEmail function**

```
public function sendEmail($thisUser){
        Mail::to($thisUser['email'])->send(new verifyEmail($thisUser));
    }
```

Both functions work well, but sometimes when i register new user i dont get the link i need to delete it from database and re-register it.

Comment: _" sometimes when i register new user i dont get the link i need to delete it from database and re-register it."_ Why can't you just **update** the record (and send email) when user clicks "resend verification link"

Comment: @Viney yep thats what i want to know how to do. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set new verify token on user or even reuse the old one. Then send the email again. Loading the user by email so they don't have to be logged in.

```
Route::post('users/verify', 'UserController@resend')

protected function resend(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
    $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
    $user->save();

    $this->sendEmail($user);

    return $user;
}
```

A very basic example form to call the controller. They need to provide the email, as you don't know which user to resend too.

```
<form action=" {!! route('resendEmail') !!}" method="POST">
    <label for="email">Your email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="example@email.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: in fact, they cannot log in before activating the account, should i make new user with the Modal or ?

Comment: Oh yh i forgot that part ;) updating the question, i would just load it by email

Comment: thanks, this might work and ill tell you once i try it

Comment: <a href="{{route('resendEmail')}}">Click here to resend verification link</a> will this work or i need a from with a button?

Comment: i kinda get error here The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Comment: you will need a form with an email field

Comment: i get 419 | Page Expired, for what reason?

Comment: hmm the verify email only lives for 60 minutes can it be that?

Comment: else i would try to remove the setting of a new verify token to see if that helps

Comment: so $user->verifyToken = 'verifyToken'? or delete it completely but then what would be sent to the users email?

Comment: just don't set a new $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    $this->sendEmail($user);

    return $user;

Comment: the answers works correctly no need to remove or add anything, i missed @csrf under form