# Resend email function causes 419 | Page Expired error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, authentication

I have this function for registering users which is pretty much the default one but i added a token to be sent to an email so the user can activate the account, otherwise the user cant log in. So i tried to add a resend function so if the first time the email is not send they can resend manually, but that causes the 419 error Page Expired.

**Register function**

```
  protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
            'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
        ]);
        $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);
        $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        return $user;
    }
```

**This is the function for resend**

```
 protected function resend(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Account::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
        $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
        $user->save();

        $this->sendEmail($user);
        return $user;
    }
```

**And i call it with this form**

```
<form action=" {!! route('resendEmail') !!}" method="POST">
      <fieldset class="youplay-input">
           <input id="email" type="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="E- 
           mail" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
      </fieldset>
      <button class="btn btn-default db" type="submit" value="Submit">
             Resend Verification Link
      </button>
</form>
```

I have discussed this with a guy but we couldnt find a good solution: [How to make resend email link function in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228923/how-to-make-resend-email-link-function-in-laravel/62238609?noredirect=1#comment110110390_62238609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your csrf token in the form. After `<form>` tag add `@csrf`.

Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
</form>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf

Comment: bruh, i feel so cringe right now, it works just fine, thank you.